# Trilinear polarity from AG perspective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider a triangle $ABC$ in the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2.$ For a point $p  \in \mathbb{P}^2$ one can define its trilinear polar line $t(p)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_polarity)). This defines a birational map to the dual plane
$$t\colon \mathbb{P}^2 \longrightarrow (\mathbb{P}^2)^{\vee}.$$
As an abstract map to a projective plane it is defined by the linear system $|2H-A-B-C|,$ but I don't see, how one can naturally understand the duality from this perspective.

Comment: what is $H$ here?

Comment: The divisor class of a line.